# array or tuple of template member functions

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

The following program attemps to store an array of `std::function`, each element pointing to a template member function.

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <bool X>
struct A {
  template <unsigned int I, bool activate = X, class = std::enable_if_t<activate>>
  unsigned int f() { return 0; }

  template <unsigned int... I>
  auto collect_allf_impl(std::integer_sequence<unsigned int, I...>) {
    return std::array<std::function<unsigned int()>, 3>{ f<I>... };
  }

  auto collect_allf() {
    return collect_allf_impl(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned int, 3>{});
  }
};

int main()
{
  A<true> x{};
  auto all = x.collect_allf();
}
```

The compiler error is

```
test.cpp:13:66: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘f’ based on conversion to type ‘std::function<unsigned int()>’
   13 |     return std::array<std::function<unsigned int()>, 3>{ f<I>... };
      |                                                                  ^
test.cpp:13:66: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘f’ based on conversion to type ‘std::function<unsigned int()>’
test.cpp:13:66: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘f’ based on conversion to type ‘std::function<unsigned int()>’
```

How do I fix this error?

**Edit**

A similar issue is found by using a tuple instead of an array. This code

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <bool X>
struct A {
  template <unsigned int I, bool activate = X, class = std::enable_if_t<activate>>
  unsigned int f() { return 0; }

  template <unsigned int... I>
  auto collect_allf_impl(std::integer_sequence<unsigned int, I...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(f<I>...);
  }

  auto collect_allf() {
    return collect_allf_impl(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned int, 3>{});
  }
};

int main()
{
  A<true> x{};
  auto all = x.collect_allf();
}
```

gives the error on compiling:

```
test.cpp:14:28: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘unsigned int (A<true>::*&&)()’ from expression of type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’
   14 |     return std::make_tuple(f<I>...);
      |                            ^~~~
```

Comment: Missing `static` for `f`: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W7nb3vM8f)

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately, the function is not supposed to be static...

Comment: Is it not `f<I>, ...` instead of `f<I>...`?

Comment: `[this](){ return this->f<I>(); }`? or `std::function<unsigned int(A&)>`...

Comment: And for the tuple: `std::make_tuple(&A::f<I>...);` ? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c57hve13h)

Comment: @user253751: no. `f<I>...` extends to `f<0>, f<1>, f<2>` in function call and initializer_list., `(f<I>, ...)` (with extra parents) would use operator comma, so would return just the last.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fs8736PYz) for the lambda. [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) might be an alternative.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks a lot! Would std::bind_front work also for an array? Or is it then a different type for each ```f<I>```?

Comment: result type only depends on parameter type, All `f<I>` are of the same type, so bind_front should be OK for the array: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fYosEjqss)

Comment: You should use &A::f<I> to get the pointer to the member function. As for your first example, you should also use std::function<unsigned(A*)> 
or std::function<unsigned(A&)> to save the pointers.